# How do I execute a python script from Java Spring Boot web application controller on AWS Elastic Beanstalk？

Tags: python, java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am using aws elastic beanstalk to host my spring boot application, how can i run python script in spring boot based on aws elastic beanstalk？

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    ProcessBuilder pb = null;

    try {
        ClassPathResource resource1 = new ClassPathResource("main.py");
        pb = new ProcessBuilder("python3", resource1.getURL().toString().substring(5));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    pb.redirectErrorStream(true); // redirect error stream to a standard output stream
    Process process = null; // Used to start the process
    try {
        process = pb.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the code snippet of my calling python script, it works fine locally, but it doesn't call python script in aws elastic beanstalk, I suspect it is because aws elastic beanstalk doesn't have python execution environment, can anyone help me?

Comment: There are errors in logs when you execute it on Beanstalk?

Comment: thanks for your help . I checked and found : python3: can't open file 'jar:file:/var/app/current/application.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory. How to write my file path will be better？

Comment: If you can paste your folder structure would help! And are you using maven? If so, since the py file is not java, it won't be automatically included in your jar, so you need to tell the project build tool to include it on your jar file

Comment: I have solved the path problem , I put the file under the resources folder , and I found that I just need to read the file through classPathResource.getInputStream() , and generate a temporary file in the root directory to get the path .

Comment: Now I can run python scripts in Elastic Beanstalk, but can't use python suite, it gives error like this: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/app/current/application.py", line 1, in import numpy as np ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'. Please do you know how to install python numpy and matplotlib in aws Elastic Beanstalk?